# How to identify a polluted water source

Tags: the-universim

I keep receiving notifications telling me one of my nugget got sick from drinking from polluted water.

How can I know if a lake is polluted?

Answer (score 1):

I think that can happen when a nugget drinks from a lake directly instead of a clean source like a well.